# Using ms-project from onedrive

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, ms-project-2010

I have a free onedrive account (via Hotmail account) that I use for word, excel type of documents. I now have a need to create a Microsoft project document (with gantt chart) but when I click on New menu item, there is no option to create a Microsoft project file. Below are the only options I get.

[image]

Could there be anyway of using Microsoft project from my free onedrive account?

Comment: I think it would be wiser to consult Microsoft's documentation than PM:SE on this issue.  Is Project included in the Microsoft's service offering?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that's the case. But I am hoping there may be some extension or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sorry.  The choices in the "new" are driven by the online versions of Word, Excel, PPT, and OneNote.  Do you have project pro for office 365 added to your Office 365 subscription?

Comment: Nops I don't have office 365 subscription. I am looking for any free solution. Is that available for free?

Comment: No sorry.  There is no version of Project that is available for free.